# A wireless temperature & humidity reader and a linked gateway with a NEXTION display, both with an Arduino esp8266

Tags: arduino

I was trying to make a wireless temperature & humidity reader and a linked gateway with a NEXTION display, both with an Arduino esp8266. I took the code from similar projects. Seems there are some problems with selecting the IP/gateway address configurations. Temperature and humidity values are not appearing in the gateway serial monitor window (Arduino IDE).

Code for both gateway and sensor node are included below.

**Gateway code:**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
float temps;
float hums;
String request;
String data;
char ssid[] = "my/net";
char pass[] = "my/pass";
WiFiServer server(80);
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 29);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 80);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (client.connected()) {
      request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
      hums = request.toFloat();
      client.flush();
      request = client.readStringUntil('\r'); 
      temps = request.toFloat();
      client.flush();
    }
    client.stop();
    NextionData();
  }
}

void NextionData() {
  data = "temps.txt=\"" + String(temps, 1) + "\"";
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  data = "hums.txt=\"" + String(hums, 1) + "\"";
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
}
```

**Sensor node code:**

```
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SparkFunBME280.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
char ssid[] = "my/net";
char pass[] = "my/pass";
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1,28);
WiFiClient client;
BME280 mySensor;
float hums;
float temps;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000);
  mySensor.setI2CAddress(0x76);
  mySensor.beginI2C();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);      
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop(){ 
  hums = mySensor.readFloatHumidity();
  temps = mySensor.readTempC();
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(hums, 2);
  Serial.print(" Temp: ");
  Serial.print(temps, 2);
  Serial.println();
  client.connect(server, 29);   
  client.println(hums,2);
  client.flush();
  delay(500);
  client.println(temps,2);
  client.flush();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Your server is listen at port 80 (`WiFiServer server(80);`). But your client is trying to connect to a different port `client.connect(server, 29);`.

Comment: @hcheung It still isn't showing. Serial output of Gateway is: Connected, IP address: 192.168.1.29
and the serial output of sensor node: Connected, IP address: 192.168.1.28
Humidity: 49.50 Temp: 22.09

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now.

### Changes I made are:

**In the gateway code:**

```
client.connect(server, 80);
```

**In the sensor node code:**

```
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1,29);//IP address of the gateway from its serial monitor
```

### The full working code:

**Gateway code:**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
float temps;
float hums;
String request;
String data;
char ssid[] = "my/net";
char pass[] = "my/pass";
WiFiServer server(80);
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 29);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 80);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (client.connected()) {
      request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
      hums = request.toFloat();
      client.flush();
      request = client.readStringUntil('\r'); 
      temps = request.toFloat();
      client.flush();
    }
    client.stop();
    NextionData();
  }
}

void NextionData() {
  data = "temps.txt=\"" + String(temps, 1) + "\"";
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  data = "hums.txt=\"" + String(hums, 1) + "\"";
  Serial.print(data);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
  Serial.write(0xff);
}
```

**Sensor Node code:**

```
#include "Wire.h"
#include "SparkFunBME280.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
char ssid[] = "my/net";
char pass[] = "my/pass";
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1,29);//IP address of the gateway from its serial monitor
WiFiClient client;
BME280 mySensor;
float hums;
float temps;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000);
  mySensor.setI2CAddress(0x76);
  mySensor.beginI2C();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);      
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop(){ 
  hums = mySensor.readFloatHumidity();
  temps = mySensor.readTempC();
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(hums, 2);
  Serial.print(" Temp: ");
  Serial.print(temps, 2);
  Serial.println();
  client.connect(server, 80);   
  client.println(hums,2);
  client.flush();
  delay(500);
  client.println(temps,2);
  client.flush();
  delay(2000);
}
```